# Let $f(x,y)$ be a continuous function from $R^2$ to $R$. If $f(x,y)=0$, does $y$ vary continuously as $x$ varies?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $f(x,y)$ be a continuous function from $R^2$ to $R$. Suppose further that for every $x$, there exists a unique $y$ such that $f(x,y)=0$. Thus we can define the function $g(x)=y$ such that $f(x,y)=0$. Is $g$ is continuous?

Hello all,

I am working on a project and I have found myself stuck on the question in the title. I am trying to find out if the roots of a continuous function $f(x,y)$ vary continuously as the argument $x$ is allowed to vary. I have a particular function $f$ in my project, but I cannot solve it for $x$ or $y$ so I am trying to do things in the abstract.

We can suppose further that there exists a unique $y$ for every $x$ such that $f(x,y)=0$. Thus we can define the function $g(x)=y$ such that $f(x,y)=0$. **I want to know if $g$ is continuous.**

From my attempts to solve this, it seems like the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) might point the way, but I am not familiar with that result and it seems like it only gives a continuous function in a subset of the domain. I was hoping to find an elementary answer but having gone though my old topology and analysis textbooks I was not able to find anything helpful.

Comment: Is the $g$ for your $f$ a function? Because it does not have to be for a general $f$.

Comment: The question in yellow makes no sense to me.

Comment: Uzman, I'm sorry, but I'm not following your comment. What do you mean by your second sentence exactly? The function $f$ has the property that for every $x$, there is a unique $y$ such that $f(x,y)=0$. I defined the function $g$ which assigns to each $x$ the corresponding unique $y$. My question is whether $g$ is continuous.

Comment: zhw, I apologize for the question in yellow not being clear. I attempted to elaborate on it and make precise my question in the text below it. If there is anything there that does not make sense, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as it turns out. One example is the (polynomial!) function
$$
f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)(xy-1),
$$
for which
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1/x, &\text{if } x\ne0, \\
0, &\text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}
$$